# Can I send/post data from GoogleSheets to external API

Tags: json, google-apps-script

Im fairly new to app dev/programming, but could anyone tell me if and post possibly a sample of how to send data from a Google Sheet to an external api?

I can so far only find examples of sending data to sheets, but I request the reverse. In json format

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has information about connecting to [external APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) by making HTTP requests with the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) class. These pages also have code samples.

If the external API requires some kind of authorization, these [libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) might be useful:

https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth1

https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2